# How to find out PID of the container using crictl

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Kubernetes is deprecating Docker as CRI engine. Now there is containerd and CRI-O, which can be used as an alternative to it. Both can be managed via crictl from cri-tools.

I need some common way to find the PID of running container.

Actually I need a **crictl** equivalent to the docker command:

```sh
# docker inspect 86cd8d605c2da -f '{{ .State.Pid }}'
9625
```

Comment: `Docker` and `Cri-O` have similar syntax. Did you try to use `crictl inspect --output go-template --template '{{.info.pid}}' <yourcontainerID>`? Output should be PID value of the container.

Comment: There is no key 'info' at all.

Answer (score 4):

As I mention in comment section, to achieve what you need using [CRI](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md) you have also use `inspect` command.

**Steps to Achieve container PID**

1. List containers to get `Container ID`.

```
$ crictl ps
CONTAINER           IMAGE               CREATED             STATE               NAME                   ATTEMPT             POD ID
cdb3feac5bdd3       35c43ace92162       3 minutes ago       Running             nginx                  0                   940b5d97fb46a
0d84f965a1c8d       6266988902813       29 minutes ago      Running             prometheus-to-sd       0                   11dad991a79e4
437c1e31d5ff1       ccbe64d6d9477       29 minutes ago      Running             metadata-agent-nanny   0                   74cbad8857254
```

2. Inspect specific container

```
$ crictl inspect cdb3feac5bdd3
{
  "status": {
    "id": "cdb3feac5bdd3981d58fb3cd2fc08cf53bbff326a38c95a77e7ec43a80fa9713",
    "metadata": {
      "attempt": 0,
      "name": "nginx"
```

In below part, you will be able to find this container `PID`.

```
"info": {
    "sandboxID": "940b5d97fb46a3c6efdf256f751cab3f3a282150efd4cdef969692d03deb4829",
    "pid": 15701,
```

Above (default) output is in `Go-Template` format (you can also chose `YAML` or `JSON` format).

```
$ crictl inspect
NAME:
   crictl inspect - Display the status of one or more containers

OPTIONS:
   --output value, -o value  Output format, One of: json|yaml|go-template|table
```

To get what you need you just need specify `path` to this information.

```
$ crictl inspect --output go-template --template '{{.info.pid}}' cdb3feac5bdd3
15701
```

#### Solution

Use below command with `containerID` to get container `PID`.

```
$ crictl inspect --output go-template --template '{{.info.pid}}' <yourContainerID>
```

Comment: This is probably correct answer. But I have no any info section in the output.I've tried latest version of crictl, so it is most probably docker runtime issue, could you provide your `crictl version` please?

Comment: What output you have if you will use this command? I've tested this on my GKE 1.19 cluster: $ crictl version
Version:  0.1.0
RuntimeName:  containerd
RuntimeVersion:  1.4.1
RuntimeApiVersion:  v1alpha2

Comment: Well, in my case I have an error ```FATA[0000] getting the status of the container "bac7563751e9a": failed to template data: template: tmplExecuteRawJSON:1:7: executing "tmplExecuteRawJSON" at <.info.pid>: map has no entry for key "info"```

Version:  0.1.0
RuntimeName:  docker
RuntimeVersion:  19.03.14
RuntimeApiVersion:  1.40.0

Comment: What output you have when you just use `crictl inspect <containerID>` ?

Comment: This also doesn't work in my case, I simply don't have that section. I'm using cri-tools 1.24.2.